# passing RPostgres or RPostgreSQL dbGetQuery() params to IN operator

Tags: r, postgresql

just wondering if there's any way to pass an arbitrary number of parameters to an `IN` clause via `params` of `dbGetQuery()`

for example, given either

```
dbcon <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres())
# or: dbcon <- dbConnect(RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL())

dbExecute(dbcon, "CREATE TEMP TABLE foo AS SELECT i FROM generate_series(1, 10) x(i);")
```

can I do anything like:

```
dbGetQuery(dbcon, "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE i IN (1, 2, 3)")
```

where the identifiers is a "short list of values", i.e. normally less than 10 integers or strings.  I thought I might be able to do something like:

```
ids <- c(1, 2, 3)
dbGetQuery(dbcon, "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE i IN $1", list(ids))
```

but the best I can do is:

```
ids <- '{1,2,3}'
dbGetQuery(dbcon, "SELECT * FROM foo WHERE i = ANY($1)", list(ids))
```

but then generating `ids` from a set of strings is somewhat error prone.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `DBI::sqlInterpolate` for generating dynamic queries. This is better than unsafely pasting queries together. However it doesn't work great for vector inputs, so for that, `dbplyr::translate_sql` works well enough if you can put up with more package imports. Example:

```
require(DBI)
require(dbplyr)

con <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = ":memory:")
month_input <- SQL(!!translate_sql(month.abb))
# Or if you don't like lazy-eval NSE nonsense
month_input <- dbplyr:::escape(month.abb)
print(month_input)
# <SQL> ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')

query <- sqlInterpolate(con, "SELECT * FROM colours WHERE month IN ?months",
  months = month_input)
print(query)
# <SQL> SELECT * FROM colours WHERE month IN ('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')
```